# consulta linq sobre 2 listas group by

Tags: c#, linq

tengo la siguiente consulta en linq, la cual toma como fuente de datos 2 listas. La primera contiene un listado de `IdProducto` y su descripción

```
public class Productos
{
    public List<Producto> lstProductos { get; set; }
}
public class Producto
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

y la otra lista tiene los productos vendidos

```
public class Venta
{
    public string ProductoId { get; set; }
    public string clienteRut { get; set; }
}

public class Ventas
{
    public List<Venta> lstVentas { get; set; }
}
```

necesito hacer la consulta de los 5 productos que mas se vendieron, ordenados por cantidad desde el que mas se vendio, hasta el que menos se vendio.

Hasta el momento tengo la siguiente consulta linq, pero no se como hacer para que me entregue la lista de los 5 primeros, ordenada de mayor a menor en base al count

```
      Venta vta1 = new Venta();
        vta1.ProductoId = "1";
        vta1.clienteRut = "121370654";

        Venta vta2 = new Venta();
        vta2.ProductoId = "2";
        vta2.clienteRut = "121370654";

        Venta vta3 = new Venta();
        vta3.ProductoId = "3";
        vta3.clienteRut = "121370654";


        List<Venta> lstVentasDia = new List<Venta>();
        lstVentasDia.Add(vta1);
        lstVentasDia.Add(vta2);
        lstVentasDia.Add(vta3);

        VentasDia vtas = new VentasDia();
        vtas.date = "2018-05-01";
        vtas.lstVentas = lstVentasDia;


        var Lista5Top = from vendidos in vtas.lstVentas
                        orderby vendidos.ProductoId
                        group vendidos by vendidos.ProductoId into Grupo
                        select new { key = Grupo.Key, cont = Grupo.Count()};
```

necesito a ese grupo de resultados, agregarle el nombre del producto que esta en la lista Productos, y ordenarlo por cantidad vendida de mayor a menor y obtener los 5 productos con mayor cantidad.

Agradecida de antemano
Gloria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

por lo que veo te falta ordenar la lista resultado y seleccionar los 5 primeros. Esto quedaría así:

```
var Lista5Top = (from vendidos in vtas.lstVentas
                orderby vendidos.ProductoId
                group vendidos by vendidos.ProductoId into Grupo
                select new { key = Grupo.Key, cont = Grupo.Count()}).OrderByDescending(v => v.cont).Take(5);
```

Un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias gerardo por tu ayuda.